# query by date but in Date/Time format in database

Tags: sql, ms-access

i am trying to display some fields from my database that are of a certain date. at the moment my query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblLessonBookings
WHERE DATE(LessonDate) = '2016-12-21'
```

The LessonDate column in the database is a date time format, and i haven't been able to just have it as a date format.

Comment: I don't get the problem

Comment: it comes up with 'Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression'

Comment: Let's start by what DB engine you really use - MySQL or Access?

Comment: Access Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Date() function doesn't take any parameters, and the string expression for the value must be properly wrapped in octothorpes, thus:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblLessonBookings
WHERE LessonDate = #2016-12-21#
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark as answered, if your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM tblLessonBookings
WHERE CAST(LessonDate as DATE) = '2016-12-21'
```

Comment: @ChristianB it will work fine in sql server, if you are using any other database then it might be give error.